# Manually installing a multifile package to “elpa/”

Tags: package, package-development

When I'm writing a new package, it's great that I can test its
installation by just issuing `M-x package-install-from-buffer`. This
will install the package with `package.el`, so that it goes under
`"~/.emacs.d/elpa"`. However, this doesn't work on multifile packages.

**What is the procedure for installing all `.el` files in the current
  directory as a single multifile package?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Emacs 25.1 now has this feature](http://endlessparentheses.com/new-in-emacs-25-1-easily-install-multifile-package-from-a-directory.html). From the `NEWS` file:

> ** `package-install-from-buffer` and `package-install-file` work on directories. This follows the same rules as installing from a `.tar` file, except the `-pkg.el` file is optional.

There are no new commands to remember. Just issue [`package-install-from-buffer`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/package-install-from-buffer) from a dired buffer, or invoke [`package-install-file`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/package-install-file) and give a directory. Whichever package is contained in that directory will be read and installed, be it single or multifile, no taring or `-pkg.el` file necessary.

Comment: Optional `-pkg.el` file is interesting. What do the values default to in that case?

Comment: @phils just like the package repositories do, it finds an elisp file with a complete package header and generates the -pkg file from that.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that's how they were generated normally. Your changes make perfect sense, then. Nice work.

Comment: Malabarba: I notice that the current docstring in trunk for `package-install-file` makes no mention of it working for directories (although, as you've said, it does).

Comment: @phils Thanks for noticing. I'm fixing it now.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that I still can't install a package from a directory where the package depends on non-elisp assets (like images)? If I need these files to be installed alongside the elisp code I still need to make the tarball dance?

Answer (score 1):

`package-install-from-buffer` says:

> The current buffer is assumed to be a single .el **or .tar file** that follows the packaging guidelines

So one presumes you can archive the directory (assuming it meets the criteria), load the tar file into Emacs, and use `package-install-from-buffer` as before?

**Edit:** Or, as lunaryorn points out, *don't* visit the archive in Emacs, and use `package-install-file`.

Comment: Sounds like a function to (re-)tar the current dir and then do the package install would be handy.

Comment: Alternatively, `M-x package-install-file`.

Comment: Doesn't work. It tries to find a `paradox/paradox-pkg.el` file inside the `tar`, and errors when it doesn't. Same for both `install-file` and `install-from-buffer`. I'm guessing I need to create this `-pkg` file as a recipe of sorts.

Comment: @Malabarba A TAR package must have a `-pkg` file, otherwise it's not a valid package, so just tar'ing a random directory won't work.  Emacs must have some place to look for the package metadata after all.  You can use MELPAs `package-build` or `cask` to create proper TAR packages from a directory tree.

Comment: Malabarba: See `C-h i g (elisp) Multi-file Packages` for details.

Answer (score 1):

`package.el` does not have good support for this use case. You have to re-run `package-install-from-buffer` every time you make an update to the package, and also `M-x find-function` and friends will not jump to the source code, but rather the copy that `package.el` puts in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`. As a consequence, I would recommend not using `package.el` for this use case (or at all, since it has a number of other problems).

Instead, you can try my package manager [`straight.el`](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el), which is explicitly designed for this use case. With `straight.el`, there is no "local installation" procedure. You just put your repository in `~/.emacs.d/straight/repos/<my-package-repo>`, and then load the package in your init-file:

```
(straight-use-package '(<my-package> :local-repo "<my-package-repo>"))
```

Anytime you make a change to the source code, autoload generation and byte-compilation is redone (once you restart Emacs). Also, you're running directly from the Git repository, so `M-x find-function` and friends will work as expected.

Finally, local and upstream versions are entirely interchangeable. `straight.el` lets you make any local changes you want, and they are treated as just as sacred as upstream changes (although `straight.el` does let you automatically [and interactively] revert your repositories to their upstream versions, if you wish). Thus, there is no concern with making any changes to your configuration if you want to do local development: just do local development. And if you have a private package that you publish, it's trivial: just push that package somewhere (and probably update the recipe in your init-file to point to that Git repository, so that `straight.el` can re-clone it from a different machine).

Unlike with `package.el`, there is no difference in the treatment of multi-file and single-file packages.

For verbose documentation about `straight.el`, including comparisons to other package managers, see the [README](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el).